# HTML link to JS folder file not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have `js` file and if I put `<script src="link_to_file"></script>` on bottom of my html page, it doesn't work.

Instead, if I put `<script>function( etc..</script>` on bottom of my html page, it works.

What is problem?

Comment: Check if file on link_to_file exists. Open in another tab to check. use inspect element to see the error

Comment: When you say it does not work? Have you viewed the element to see if the path even exists? Are you using a framework, wordpress or what?

Comment: @JurePotocnik link_to_file exits but isn't load..

Comment: @Dan not working in <script src="link_to_file"></script> buy working on <script>function( etc..</script>

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I put both of link on bottom of site..

Comment: @Marko.pwn I get that but it still does not make sense what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Dan I wish put js code on js file...

Comment: You can put your js in head and you can add a document ready function to it…  this way DOM (html) is loaded before your script

Comment: @Marko.pwn Show us more and we can help

Comment: I put this on bottom of my page
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ .. });
</script>
this script is working, but i put this on my bottom of page
<scirpt src="js/style.js"></script>
this is not working

Comment: Do you have jquery loaded?

Comment: @t0mm13b yes, look down to fix new problem..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML**

*bottom*

```
<script src="external-script.js><script>
```

**EXTERNAL JS**

Add `$(document).ready(function () {})`

- Make sure jQuery is loaded first.
- Check your global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using the right path, that's depending om your folder structure. For example, if the js file is in the same folder as your html file, use

```
<script src = 'fileName.js'></script>
```

Do not forget to include the .js extension at the end of the file name. The file name should be same as the name of your js file. 
Anyhow, you do not have to put the script in the head section as someone has suggested. It's in fact, not a good practice.

Comment: Are the files in the same folder or in separate folders?

Comment: It would really help if I could see your folder structure

Comment: In separate folders.. i fix it but i have a new problem, slider doesn't working.. i put all slider functions on js file but this functions doesn't working on page?

Comment: `<script = '../folder/filename.js'></script>`

Comment: Kindly post your code ... It will be much easier telling where the problem is. Post both the javascript and html code.

Comment: Problem in this var slider = <?= $slider; ?>; 
Problem in this is i put this code in html script working, but i put in js file not working

Comment: Whole file, or at least a substantial part of it. You are not supposed to  ask a question with one line of code.